# How to fetch rows ending with specific value from hbase using hbase shell

Tags: java, hbase, mapr

How to fetch rows that ends with specific value in Hbase?
For example I have below rowskeys in my table

```
   D1|V1
   D2|V1
   D3|V2
   D4|V1
```

Now I need all rows that ends with V1. In this example I should get D1,D2 and D4.

Can some one suggest how to achieve this in Hbase

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it using below:

```
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
   scan 'tableName', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("SubString"))}
```

and through Java

```
    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
    List<String> referenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultScanner results = null;
    String substr= "V1";
    RowFilter rowfilter = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator(substr));
    filterList.addFilter(rowfilter);
    Scan prefilterScan = new Scan();
    prefilterScan.setFilter(filterList);
```